# Executing CostDistance Function in ArcPy gives Error 999999?

Tags: arcpy, spatial-analyst, error-999999, cost-path

I am attempting to create a least cost path using ArcPy for automation. I have the starting/end points and cost surface raster already assembled, so I am just using ArcPy to automate through my dataset. Upon running the script, though, I receive an error at line 24: "CostDist = arcpy.sa.CostDistance(...".

Here is the code block:

```
import os
import arcpy
from arcpy.sa import *
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput= True
arcpy.env.extent = ('H:\\IAS GIS Information\\Geodatabase\\Island_Isolation\\Tidal_Stream\\Tide_LCP\\Extent_3\\Tide_Extent3.shp')
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("spatial")

arcpy.env.workspace = ('H:\\IAS GIS Information\\Geodatabase\\Island_Isolation\\Tidal_Stream\\Tide_LCP\\Extent_3')
TargetWorkspace = ('H:\\IAS GIS Information\\Geodatabase\\Island_Isolation\\Tidal_Stream\\Tide_LCP\\Extent_3')

SourcePoints =  ("H:\\IAS GIS Information\\Geodatabase\\Island_Isolation\\Tidal_Stream\\Tide_LCP\\Extent_3\\Tide_Extent3_Source_Points.shp")
DestinationPoints = ("H:\\IAS GIS Information\\Geodatabase\\Island_Isolation\\Tidal_Stream\\Tide_LCP\\Extent_3\\Tide_Extent3_Destination_Points.shp")
CostSurface = ("H:\\IAS GIS Information\\Geodatabase\\Island_Isolation\\Tidal_Stream\\Tide_LCP\\Extent_3\\Tide_Extent_3_CostSurface.tif")

CostDist = ('H:\\IAS GIS Information\\Geodatabase\\Island_Isolation\\Tidal_Stream\\Tide_LCP\\Extent_3')
Backlink = ('H:\\IAS GIS Information\\Geodatabase\\Island_Isolation\\Tidal_Stream\\Tide_LCP\\Extent_3')
CostPath = ('H:\\IAS GIS Information\\Geodatabase\\Island_Isolation\\Tidal_Stream\\Tide_LCP\\Extent_3')

for i in range (int(arcpy.GetCount_management(DestinationPoints).getOutput(0))): #Use the "getOutput() to start the FID count"
    if os.path.exists(Backlink + str(i)):
       os.remove(Backlink + str(i))
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(DestinationPoints, "endpointA" + str(i), ' "IN_FID_A" = ' + str(i))
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(SourcePoints, "sourcepointA" + str(i), ' "IN_FID_A" = ' + str(i))
    CostDist = arcpy.sa.CostDistance("endpointA" + str(i), CostSurface, out_backlink_raster = "BackLinkA"+str(i))
    CostDist.save("CostDistA" + str(i))
    CostPath = arcpy.sa.CostPath("sourcepointA" + str(i), "CostDistA" + str(i), "BackLinkA" + str(i))
    CostPath.save("CostPathA" + str(i))
```

The execution error reads: "ExecuteError: ERROR 999999: Error executing function. Failed to create raster dataset Failed to execute (CostDistance)."

I have used this code previously with no issues so I am not sure about what is making the script fail.

Comment: Does the field IN_FID_A exist and is it populated with unique and contiguous numbers with a starting value of 0? It's possible that one of your input layers is empty which may be causing the error. As your input DestinationPoints is a shapefile you could calc IN_FID_A = FID to ensure contiguity.

Comment: If the code's the same as worked before then maybe it's the data.  I think you should re-test your code against data that you know worked previously to see if it still does.

Comment: IN_FID_A does exist and is populated properly- I used the FID field to provide unique numbers. As for re-testing the code with previous data, the code still fails and provides the same error. A backlink raster is created, though, but it is empty and cannot be deleted in Arc. I have had to go to the actual file and delete it manually. Pretty odd.

Comment: That sounds like a locking situation, do you have more than one Esri session open (Arc Map, catalog, scene)? Perhaps a quick reboot might solve the problem (can't hurt).

Comment: I thought the same thing too- I restarted ArcMap and even rebooted the entire computer but that didn't work either! Good Thought though.

Comment: How long is the name of the output raster? Have you tried running it in a directory that does not contain spaces? ie: C:\temp?

Answer (score 1):

The issue appeared to have been associated with the file location(s): I was able to resolve the problem by moving all associated files to a different directory. As Keagan Allan May eluded to, the issue may have been with having spaces in the previous directory. Thanks for the help everyone!